# Calibrating an accelerometer

Tags: accelerometer

I have a device which contains an accelerometer. I'm looking for calibrating my 3D accelerometer.

I'm proceeding as follows:

The first time, I put my device in a flat position (rest) and I obtained these values :

```
x = -0.02

y = -0.02

z = -1.02
```

I applied Pythagoras's theorem to calculate total acceleration  : `A = sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z)`

Normally, when I subtract -1 (9.8 m/s2) from A, it should give 0 m/s but in my case it gives me : 0.01, so can I consider that my accelerometer is calibrated with a litle error = 0.01 or should I subtract 0.01 from all my outputs data for each axes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It depends on the application, how much sensitivity you need. Error 0.01 is from all the three components. If you want to use each axis reading then take average of multiple readings and find difference as you did.

Comment: @Nadosh: Thak you very much for your reply. the sensitivity of my accelerometer is : 64. If i understand, i calculate average of some readings data then i substract 1 from it. for example, here i taked a 5 first readings values of X-axis: -0.343, -0.25, -0.3125, -0.281, -O.219. So i calculate avearge of theses readings values: AVG =(-0.343 -0.25+ -0.3125+ -0.281+ -O.219)/5 = 0.279.After this, i substract 1 from the averges's result ( 0.279 - 1)? is this what did you mean? Thanks in advance

Comment: yes but subtraction of 1 is only if the axis is in gravity direction. Can you share which accelerometer are you using ?

Comment: check this http://starfinder.altervista.org/acceq3.png

Comment: @nadosh: Thanks for your reply. in fact, i'm using Kinoix j9's Accelerometer http://www.willow.co.uk/html/components/com_virtuemart/shop_image/product/OEM%20Component%20Level%20Accelerometers/pdfs/KXTJ9-1007%20Specifications%20Rev%204.pdf.

Comment: Please how can i know if my my axis is in gravity direction? thanks in advance

Comment: check in page 12, axis of device is mention and depending on the placement of accelerometer, you can say about gravity

Comment: Thanks for your help. but i'm a newbie in analyzing signal. can you please explain me more. Thanks

Comment: Lets say your you  are working with +/- 2G sensitivity (table in page 12 ). If you keep the device infront of you by making Pin 1 on upper left that position in this position is gravity is along y-axis. similarly other positions.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nadosh. The proble here that i can't know the position of Pin1 because my accelerometer is included in a device which name's Sensortag(http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/SensorTag_User_Guide)

Comment: How are you getting 3 readings ? are you parsing 3-bytes ? if yes they are x,y.z in order.

Comment: is my diagram correct?

Comment: yes, your diagram is correct. you can also verify it by moving in direction of x,y,z and compare the values your get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nadosh:
[image]Yes, data acceleration is 3 bytes. x,y,z in order did you mean line this